# To what depth do I use multiprocessing across many functions in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing

Forewarning: I know a lot of this code doesn't make sense, I simplified most of it for the sake of my question, and I didn't want to remove a lot of the functions that are present in the true code for the sake of representing what I'm working with. But this way you don't have to scroll through a few hundred more lines of jargon. It does run correctly for me in this form.

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to get around script() maxing out my memory when I run this the way I want to run it. Note below, there's two eqs functions, one is a simplified version, that runs using only one equation I've made. The real one is commented out. Ideally, I want to run the one with all six equations.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, Data, RealData
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import itertools
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

def anym(ay):
    return True

def avyrns(avars):
    return avars

def vay(me):
    xem = np.transpose(me)
    xamma = np.array([])
    for xim in range(len(xem)):
        jim = stats.variation(xem[xim]) * 100
        xamma = np.hstack((xamma, jim))
    return xamma


def lin(lx, ly, lstdd, lstdc, lqcd, lqcc, lqcdi):
    lslope, lintercept, lr_value, lp_value, lstd_err = stats.linregress(lx, ly)
    lnewstanlinvals = (lstdd - lintercept) / lslope
    lnewqclinvals = (lqcd - lintercept) / lslope
    lern = lnewstanlinvals, lnewqclinvals, lstdd, lstdc, lqcd, lqcc, lqcdi
    return np.array([lern, ['Linear', 'stats.lingress', [lx], [ly]]])

def sq(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**(2) + b*x + c

def sqa(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*x**(3) + b*x**(2) + c*x + d

def squin(sqx, sqy, sqstdd, sqstdc, sqqcd, sqqcc, sqqcdi):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(sq, sqx, sqy)
    sqnewstanvals = sq(sqstdd, *popt)
    sqnewqcvals = sq(sqqcc, *popt)
    sqern = sqnewstanvals, sqnewqcvals, sqstdd, sqstdc, sqqcd, sqqcc, sqqcdi
    return np.array([sqern, ['x^3', 'scipy.curve_fit', [sqx], [sqy]]])

def squan(sqx, sqy, sqstdd, sqstdc, sqqcd, sqqcc, sqqcdi):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(sqa, sqx, sqy)
    sqnewstanvals = sqa(sqstdd, *popt)
    sqnewqcvals = sqa(sqqcc, *popt)
    sqern = sqnewstanvals, sqnewqcvals, sqstdd, sqstdc, sqqcd, sqqcc, sqqcdi
    return np.array([sqern, ['x^2', 'scipy.curve_fit', [sqx], [sqy]]])

def func(beta, x):
    y = beta[0]+beta[1]*x+beta[2]*x**3
    return y

def leastsq(oqx, oqy, oqstdd, oqstdc, oqqcd, oqqcc, oqqcdi):
    modata = RealData(oqx, oqy)
    model = Model(func)
    odr = ODR(modata, model, [0,0,0])
    odr.set_job(fit_type=2)
    output = odr.run()
    newstdv = func(output.beta, oqstdd)
    newqcv = func(output.beta, oqqcd)
    oern = newstdv, newqcv, oqstdd, oqstdc, oqqcd, oqqcc, oqqcdi
    return np.array([oern, ['ODR-Leastsq', 'scipy.ODR', [oqx], [oqy]]])

def odri(oqx, oqy, oqstdd, oqstdc, oqqcd, oqqcc, oqqcdi):
    modata = RealData(oqx, oqy)
    model = Model(func)
    odr = ODR(modata, model, [0,0,0])
    odr.set_job(fit_type=1)
    output = odr.run()
    newstdv = func(output.beta, oqstdd)
    newqcv = func(output.beta, oqqcd)
    oern = newstdv, newqcv, oqstdd, oqstdc, oqqcd, oqqcc, oqqcdi
    return np.array([oern, ['ODR-Implicit', 'scipy.ODR', [oqx], [oqy]]])

def odre(oqx, oqy, oqstdd, oqstdc, oqqcd, oqqcc, oqqcdi):
    modata = RealData(oqx, oqy)
    model = Model(func)
    odr = ODR(modata, model, [0,0,0])
    odr.set_job(fit_type=0)
    output = odr.run()
    newstdv = func(output.beta, oqstdd)
    newqcv = func(output.beta, oqqcd)
    oern = newstdv, newqcv, oqstdd, oqstdc, oqqcd, oqqcc, oqqcdi
    return np.array([oern, ['ODR-Explicit', 'scipy.ODR', [oqx], [oqy]]])

#def eqs(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi):
#    return np.array([lin(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi), squin(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi), squan(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi), leastsq(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi), odri(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi), odre(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi)])

def eqs(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi):
    return np.array([lin(ex, ey, estdd, estc, eqcd, eqcc, eqcdi)])

def script():
    varis = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    conaris = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    stdvars = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    stcvars = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    qcdvars = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    qccvars = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    qcdil = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

    xanna = 0
    holder = np.linspace(0, len(stdvars)-1, len(stdvars)).astype(np.int64)
    for li in range(len(holder)+1):
      for subset in itertools.combinations(holder, li):
          if li > 7:
              holding =  np.int64(subset)
              linmo =  eqs(varis[holding], conaris[holding], stdvars, stcvars, qcdvars, qccvars, qcdil)
              for xant in range(len(linmo)):
                  if anym(linmo[xant][0]) == True:
                      if xanna == 0:
                          linmarv = avyrns(linmo[xant][0])
                          xanna = 1
                          mim = np.array([linmo[0], linmarv[0], linmarv[1]])
                      elif xanna == 1:
                          linmarv = avyrns(linmo[xant][0])
                          mam = np.array([linmo[0], linmarv[0], linmarv[1]])
                          mim = np.vstack((mim, mam))
    print mim[-10:]

script()
```

The one-equation version runs this code fine without multiprocessing, but I figured it's a good starting point to determine if I'm using the multiprocessing function correctly. So I've added these additions, and gotten it to work:

```
import multiprocessing
def throw_away_function(_):
    return script()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
    results = pool.map(throw_away_function, range(10))
    print(results)
```

At first I was a little too excited that this worked on the single-equation version, so I uncommented the real version and tried it. It seemed to be working well, neither the processor nor the memory were even close to maxing out. It ran for ~3 minutes before I hear a string of the windows 10 3-tone 'you can't do that' noises happening so close to each other that it sounded like my computer actually gave off a fart.

My screen immediately went black, with just the mouse showing. ~5 minutes later the screen comes back and a lot of other applications crashed, but python didn't! Although my CPU processes were all at < 2%, which is extremely suspicious as the code still didn't return my desired result. 10 minutes after trying to restart the computer it finally restarted and came back the same as always.

I'm also not sure if I can just multiprocess script() by itself, or if I should be doing this for all the functions I've made? All of the functions get used by script() so I assumed that this would by default incorporate all of the other functions into the multiprocessing.

But I'm clearly doing something wrong here, is there anyone who could lend me some help advice on making this process more efficient?

Comment: Without trying to go through all of that code, what makes you think that `multiprocessing` could enable you to do something that would otherwise exceed your available memory without it? Python, without multiprocessing, will continue to consume memory until your system basically crashes (hits the hardware limitation), regardless of multiprocessing.

Comment: I thought that's what multiprocessing did to begin with? I had someone refer me to multithreading for a previous problem and I went and learned a bit more about these things. The problem I ran into here seemed to be CPU-bound, so I figured this would be a useful way out. Was I wrong?

Comment: Well, multi-threading won't help with a CPU-bound problem due to the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so you could normally turn to multi-processing for a potential way around that. However, even if your code is CPU-bound, no code will give you more RAM. Perhaps find the most memory-hungry part of your code and see if there's a way around that. Do you need it all in memory?

Comment: Actually, you got me tinkering with something. This whole thing shouldn't be this slow in general. My odri equation is taking up massive amounts of memory for some reason I can't explain, but once I remove that everything is hunky-dory. Well, I guess this question was unnecessary, I was just a bit confused. Thanks :)

Comment: I thought confusion was part of the day-job, so no worries there :) I don't think I can answer what was going wrong in `odri` with this example. I suggest you post your own answer to this question and accept it to close it, then try hunt down your error there. If you don't understand it, boil it down to the smallest, repeatable example, and post as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odri equation is clogging up memory for some reason I'm not sure of, I thought the whole process was memory intensive but it actually wasn't, I don't even need to multiprocess this.

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: I removed the odri for now, I have other fittings I need to make working models for. I can get my implicit odr back eventually, but I'll have to work on that one separately.